# How to load cart with a specified quote id (with all products) and redirect user to cart on clicking a url?

Tags: magento-1

I have a custom module which share the cart to others users via email.
I want to to add a link in the email template so that on clicking the user should be redirected to cart page with populated cart.

I will be using quote id to load the cart but I am not getting the logic that how can I encrypt the url and share it.

What should be the parameters that I should pass in the url?

I can load like following

```
$cartId = 774;
$cart = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($cartId);
print_r($cart);
```

Now I want a url on clicking which the cart must be populated with this quote.

Please suggest some idea.

Comment: You mean the users that click on the shared link will get the same cart, or a clone of the original cart?

Comment: @Marius Yes,(clone of original cart) Actually I want to email my cart to other users so that they can also purchase same item.  I want to share a link in email on clicking that they should get the car pre populated.  similar to http://shop.sutunam.com/share-cart-magento-extension.html

Comment: @Marius Could suggest some solution or any approach for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't rely on id. It's risky.
Instead I would add a new column in the quote table called `code` that should be a random code.
Then generate a link like `checkout/cart/clone/code/{code_goes_here}`.
This url will be mapped to a controller action that searches for the cart with the code `{code_goes_here}`.
if it finds one it will load it like you do `Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($cartId);` but instead of `load($cartId)` you have to have a method `loadByCode` or something like that.

Then you have to merge the quote with the current quote of the customer.

You will find the code to merge 2 quotes in `Mage_Checkout_Model_Session::loadCustomerQuote`
And for sharing you can do something similar to how the wishlist share does it.
Look into `Mage_Wishlist_SharedController::cartAction`

Comment: If I use encrypted url or data like base64_encode(Mage::helper('core')->getEncryptor()->encrypt($data) Will it be safe?

Comment: @Muk what do you mean by safe? I suggest using a random code. If someone finds the algorithm for encrypting the quote id, he can see what everyone has in the cart just by trying different ids. I think this is the same reason Magento used a random code for wishlist share.

Answer (score 5):

Like @Marius said, for security reason you should add a security code to prevent anyone from entering random quote id which  loading other user quote

Email url `site.com/restorequote/quote_id/1234/code/{random char}`

Then store the random char in the quote when generating your email

```
//$cartId - get quote id from url link
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($cartId);
//Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->replaceQuote($quote);
if(url random char == quote->getRandomChar()){
  $quote->setIsActive(true)->save();
  $this->_redirect('checkout/cart', array("_forced_secure" => true));
}
else{
   //error message
}
```

Comment: this code sounds interesting. Would you want to share the code? Or can I find it on Github? We had the exact same question (hand over quote to customer with a unique link)

Comment: @snh_nl... sorry, I did not actually wrote any code for this. Try create a email template with a url that contain the quote id and md5 of the created_at. Then create a controller that load the quote and check the md5 of the created_at. If you have any issue, just create a new question and add the link here